# How to manage multiple version of codes in Git?

Tags: git, github

Here is the story,
I have one large software source codes, web front-end, it has literally hundreds reaching almost a thousand clients, my plan is that each of those clients will have direct link to a specific branch in this git repo (for the source code), no client will share a same branch name in our git repo.

Now, it has challenges in the way i deploy a feature on some clients or even all clients.

Let say currently all branches (all clients) start from same commit history, i.e.:

`git log` on branch: `master`, `client1`, ..., `client900`:

- commit10
- commit9
- ...
- commit1

Then, from branch `master` I created one development branch for `feature_a`, then I develop all necessary code for this feature,

My plan is only to deploy `feature_a` to 100 clients, i.e. merge all commit from `feature_a` to `client1` to `client100`.

It went flawlessly.

Then, from branch `master` again I created one development branch for `feature_b`, then I develop all necessary code for this feature,

Now, my plan is to deploy `feature_b` to all of clients, i.e. merge all commit from `feature_b` to `client1` to `client900`.

The goal is for `client1` to `client100` to have 2 features while the rest only have 1 additional feature.

Since developing `feature_a` and `feature_b` requires me to change many of the same files, it will cause merge conflict on branch `client1` to `client100`,

Fixing hundreds if not thousands of merge conflict is not an option for me, is there any better way to approach this problem? or is there any better git repo architecture design or approach so that problem on deploying a feature to some and then all clients will be seamless?

Comment: I would probably have just one repository that has all features in it, and some way to toggle optional features on/off for each client. That way you don't have to merge each feature for each client.

Comment: Any common code should be common via subtrees, submodules, npm packages, nuget packages, etc. Anything specific for a client could be represented with feature flags or via interfaces and client specific implementations loaded at run time. Managing 100 (let alone 10) entire copies of a software work is madness.

Comment: @Andy but for security purpose i dont want client 900 to have `feature_a` code in it, since its front end code, only `client1` to `client100` will have `feature_a` code

Comment: @xcode That's precisely why you shouldn't use `git` as a deployment tool.  (One of many reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with this way of structuring your code, and I agree with the commenters saying you should be using feature flags. If you're concerned about code even getting to clients, then you should consider feature flags as part of your build process so a given artifact only has the features you want.

---

That being said, for a "small" number of features you can improve your situation by using tags.

Rather than each client having a unique branch, give each client a unique tag. Most git operations will perform the same, but it's significantly easier to change what code they point to.

Then your branches should be feature based. So you will have `feature_a` that only contains code for feature a. Then you have `feature b` with code only for feature b. Then you have `feature_a_b` that contains BOTH feature a and b - and you only have to resolve conflicts in a single spot.

For deployment, you just change the tags to point to the branch you want - `client1` to `client100` point to `feature_a_b` and `client101` to `client900` point to `feature_b`.

Then suppose client562 decides to upgrade (or whatever) and now they need feature a. Super easy - just change the tag `client562` to point to `feature_a_b`. No merging necessary!

---

**But what if there are client specific changes?**

Make a client branch off of the feature branch and make the changes there.

**But what if there are client specific changes and they change features?**

With the client branch, just rebase the client specific commits onto the appropriate feature branch.

---

This gets more complex the more features are introduce, specifically you'll need `2^(n-1)` feature branches where `n` = the number of features. In practice, this may be lower if certain features must be present for other features to work (ie feature j only makes sense if feature c is present), but this is a fair approximation.

However, this is a very convoluted way to do this and I would hate to actually work in this environment. I still think it's an improvement over managing 1,000 branches, but I hope you'll consider a different way of managing your deployments.